# Login Facebook using C# ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I'm trying to log in to Facebook using aspx but i can't get the email from Facebook plugin log in so any one have a sample for that.

all i want to get the email in variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting user e-mail with facebook C# sdk](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6672127/getting-user-e-mail-with-facebook-c-sdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created this code. Hopefully it will help you; it works for me and it gets the e-mail after login.

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream"></fb:login-button>
```

Script code is:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');

        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            alert(response.email);
        });

        FB.logout(function(response) {
            console.log('Logged out.');
        });
    });
    } else {
        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
}, {scope: 'email'});
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login)